# w2012 file server. Deleted folder reappears and can't be deleted

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-permissions, file-sharing

On a windows 2012 R2 File Server when clients app removes a folder it reappears with access denied. I can browse to the folder which contains the inaccessible folder, I can run dir command and see it. But when trying to delete it (with cmd shell in adminsitrator mode or powershell) I get either access is denied or "the path does not exist"

I've closed it in open files in Computer Management window. I've tried to get access right to the folders in question but it only says "access is denied" - I do that from administrators account (either computer or domain administrators won't work). I've tried unlocker programs. All for nothing.

The problem is solved after reboot. The locked folder disappears. The problem is that I cannot restart the server each time this happens. This is production server, and our clients use it 24/7. Has anyone encountered similar issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I had similar experiences before, running chkdsk helped.

Comment: thx for the comment. chkdsk din't find any errors. I'm really lost here. It seems that only restart helps.

Comment: I've seen this a lot when the App isn't releasing the file handle properly. Instead of doing a full restart, just restart the service that is doing the deleting. If that clears it contact the app authors.